# Selbst oder selber?

Tags: word-choice

Sind folgende Sätze beide richtig?

> a) Das haben Sie doch **selber** gesagt!
>
> b) Das haben Sie doch **selbst** gesagt!

Wenn ja, gibt es dann einen Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

Comment: Vielleicht auch: 

"Das haben Sie doch selber gesagt!" versus "Das haben selbst Sie doch gesagt!"

Comment: @thei: In deinem zweiten Satz hat 'selbst' aber eine ganz andere Funktion (selbst = sogar).

Comment: @markus: Ja, das stimmt.

Comment: @thei: Fragen sind natürlich auch Sätze aber ich würde Fragen als eine echte Untermenge der Sätze betrachten, welche auch Befehle, Aussagen.....sein können. Über  das Vertauschen von "selb*" und "doch"  hast Du sicher Recht: ich hatte übrigens zuerst die andere Version  geschrieben und wollte sie dann "verbessern"!

Comment: @Georges Vielleicht verstehe ich dich nicht richtig, aber "Das haben Sie selber doch gesagt!" ist eben gerade keine Frage.

Comment: @thei: Nein, mein Kommentar betraf Deinen zweiten  Vorschlag:  *"Fragen" durch "Sätze" ersetzen"*

Comment: Ich habe mal ein wenig editiert. Ich hoffe, das war im Sinne des OPs.

Comment: Ja,danke splattne: der OP findet seine Frage jetzt schöner mit diesem milden eleganten Gelb in der Mitte:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Korrekt sind beide Varianten. Ursprünglich waren sie auch etwa gleichwertig, in jüngerer Zeit hat sich jedoch eine gewisse Verschiebung von *selber* zum Umgangssprachlichen ergeben.

Zur Herkunft der Formen findet sich Folgendes im Grimm.
Zunächst erklärt man die grimmsche Vermutung, es handele sich um Steigerungsformen:

> das nebeneinander der formen selb-selber-selbst könnte es nahe legen, in diesen letzteren steigerungsformen zu sehen; diese auffassung hat in der that Grimm gr. 3, 646—48 vertreten, gestützt namentlich auf die parallelen der antiken und romanischen sprachen: gr. αὐτότερος, αὐτότατος, altlat. (plautin.) ipsissimus, mittellat. *met-ipsimus (neben *met-ipse) als vorstufe von ital. medesimo, rhätorom. medem, altfranz. meisme, franz. même, span. mismo, port. mesmo (Diez4 208).

Tatsächlich ist die Bildung aber so erfolgt:

> allein die sprachlichen thatsachen führen auf eine andre erklärung: selb(e)st ist entstanden aus selbes durch anfügung eines unorganischen t (wie in einst, sonst u. a.); dieses ist, wie selber, eine erstarrte flexionsform, nämlich der starke gen. diese beziehung entgeht Grimm nicht; aber er nimmt in selbes (wie in eines) abfall des t an (während er s. 92 eben wegen des nl. zelfs das adv. selbst als superlativ zu fassen ablehnt). band 4, s. 358, anm. 2 kehrt er dann zweifelnd zu der richtigen auffassung zurück (die er schon a. a. o. in betracht gezogen, aber verworfen hatte); weiter sind dann für sie eingetreten Frommann mundarten 3, 186, 55. Weigand 2, 692 (wie früher schon Adelung). sie wird bewiesen durch folgende umstände: a) die form selb(e)s findet sich früher und in der ältern sprache sehr gewöhnlich; das später auftretende selbst ist also aus ihr entstanden und nicht umgekehrt; b) die formen selbs und selbst, und nur diese, werden noch massenhaft als genitiv empfunden und verwendet. allerdings ist die form von der sprache selbst früh als superlativ empfunden worden, s. unten II, 4.

II, 4 schließlich erklärt noch die schon frühzeitige Empfindung als Superlativ, obwohl es sich nicht um einen solchen handelt. Möglicherweise ergibt sich daraus aber auch, warum *selbst* auch heute noch als etwas stärker oder passender (in der Schriftsprache) als *selber* empfunden wird.

Comment: Warum sind im Zitat fast keine Grossbuchstaben?

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: Weil die Großschreibung im Deutschen tatsächlich eine eher junge Erfindung ist, der Grimm jedoch ab Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts entstanden ist. Die Brüder Grimm waren außerdem Verfechter der kompletten Kleinschreibung.

Comment: Siehe dazu auch: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-is-the-origin-of-the-rules-about-the-capitalization-of-the-first-letter-of-e/182#182

Comment: Deine Antwort ist *phantastisch* und *geistreich*, was vom einem *ghost* zu erwarten ist...Du beantwortest meine Frage genau, indem Du die stilistische Verschiebung von *selber* sur Umgangssprache beschreibst. Die Vermutung und ihre Widerlegung , dass  selber und selbst Steigerungsformen sein könnten sind faszierend.Vielen Dank, Oregonghost!

Comment: bitte solche Zitate aus dem Grimm für den Fragesteller kurz zusammenfassen. Wenn du davon ausgehst, dass er den Grimmm nicht kennt dann wird er ihn wh auch nicht lesen können! Außerdem muss der Fragesteller kein "Native" sein, dann würde so etwas schnell zu einer wertlosen Antwort.

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: Ich bin da unschlüssig. Der Grimm ist sicher nicht leichtverdaulich, aber lesbar ist er schon. Die Kernpunkte habe ich außerdem zusammengefasst, es fehlt eigentlich maximal ein Satz über *selbes => selbest => selbst*. Aber das sagt ja auch schon der erste Satz aus dem zweiten Zitat, und der ist doch recht verständlich. Oder findest du, dass konkret noch mehr an Zusammenfassung fehlt? Wertlos wäre die Antwort übrigens trotzdem nicht, die eigentliche Frage wird ja so oder so von mir beantwortet.

Comment: Samuel, ich kann und will nicht für andere sprechen, aber persönlich habe ich diese Auszüge sehr genossen: ich hätte sie allein nie gefunden.

Comment: dann ist alles gut :) ich hab nur gemerkt dass ich mir plötzlich selbst schwer tue, als Muttersprachler. Darum hab ich das dazugeschrieben ;) Oregon bekam ja trotzdem sein +1 da ich Grim-Zitate gern habe

Comment: Man muss dazu sagen, dass ich bei so langen Zitaten etwas faul bin und sie einfach reinkopiere. Im Original ist da auch noch relativ viel formatiert (Kapitälchen für Namen, viel kursiv, bestimmte Zitate rechtsbündig, wobei ich da wenigstens Absätze mache), das bleibt aber beim Kopieren auf der Strecke. Ich schaue nur, dass man es einigermaßen flüssig lesen kann.

Comment: Schön, Samuel. Jetzt sind wir alle drei zufrieden!

Answer (score 6):

Ja, beide Beispiele sind vollkommen richtig.

Normalerweise können *selbst* und *selber* beliebig miteinander ausgetauscht werden, wenn sie im Sinne von *persönlich* oder *alleine* (in Kontrast zu anderen Möglichkeiten) verwendet werden.

> Ich habe meine Fahrrad selbst repariert.

entspricht genau

> Ich habe meine Fahrrad selber repariert.

Hier sind selbst/selber **Demonstrativpronomen**. Es ist Geschmacksache, ob jemand das eine oder andere Wort vorzieht.

---

Wenn *selbst* hingegen im Sinne von *sogar* oder *auch* verwendet wird, darf es nicht mit *selber* ersetzt werden. Das folgende Beispiel

> Selbst der beste Meteorologe kann nicht voraussagen, ob es in drei Wochen regnen wird.

darf **nicht**

> Selber der beste Meteorologe kann nicht voraussagen, ob es in drei Wochen regnen wird.
>   *(falsch)*

lauten.

Hier wird *selbst* als **Adverb** (Fokuspartikel) verwendet.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt keinen Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Varianten!

> Das haben Sie doch selber gesagt.
>     Das haben Sie doch selbst gesagt.
>   Das haben Sie selber doch auch schon gesagt.
>     Das haben Sie selbst doch auch schon gesagt.

Answer (score 2):

Anhand von zwei Beispielen möchte ich verdeutlichen, wie sich der Sinn der Aussage allein durch den Satzbau verändert:

> 1) Das haben doch selbst Sie gesagt: *Even you said this*
>
> 2) Das haben doch Sie selbst gesagt: *But it was you who said this*
>
> 3) Das haben Sie doch selbst gesagt: *It was you who said this*

Im Beispiel 1) ist nur *selbst* richtig, während im Beispiel 2) und 3) sowohl *selbst* als auch *selber* richtig sein können.

Comment: Bitte um Kritik/Korrektur der Übersetzung (da bin ich etwas unsicher)

Comment: Maybe the point is that the second version emphasizes: "But it was you who said this, not someone else." while the third version emphasizes that you said it versus the absence of it "But you said it yourself that I should water the flowers, so why are you angry that I watered your flower dress?"

Comment: Bei heutigem Gebrauch würde ich dir bei Beispiel 1 zustimmen, da geht es ja um die Bedeutung als *sogar*. Der Grimm führt jedoch ein Beispiel von Goethe an: "aber am tiefsten trafst du doch mich, den freund, der im arm dich 
hält, den selber der schein früherer leiche geschreckt. " Zumindest früher wurde *selber* mitunter also als *sogar* verwendet, aber selbst damals war es eher selten.